# Plotly: ImportError: cannot import name 'exceptions'

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, plotly, python-import

im using Python 3.6.4 in the Anaconda 3 built and for some reason I am no longer able to import Plotly, even-though I just used it hours before.

When running `import plotly`, I get the following error message:

```
import plotly
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-1-6361d2547ebc>", line 1, in <module>
import plotly

File "C:\Users\janfe\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\plotly\plotly\plotly.py", line 30, in <module>
from plotly import exceptions, files, session, tools, utils

ImportError: cannot import name 'exceptions'
```

As indicated above, yesterday, I closed my IDE (Spyder), to take a break, came back and when I wanted to run the exact same script which worked when I left it, the error message appeared. After googling around for a bit, I stumbled upon some people with the exact same question to whom it was proposed to uninstall or upgrade plotly via pip. None of that worked for me.

Thank you for helping me out!

Jan

Edit: The problem went away and came back(!) when I reinstalled (uninstalled and installed again) the whole anaconda build including python etc.. First, it went fine, but again - when I closed and reopened Spyder I had exactly the same issue. The only thing I did between opening Spyder the first time (after reinstallation) and closing was to run some code which included a change of the working directory (something I'm used to doing when coding in R-Studio) - could that be the problem?

PS: My question is similar to the following questions, both of which have not been solved:

- [Plotly import error for exceptions module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42784650/plotly-import-error-for-exceptions-module)
- [plotly cannot import name exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46296982/plotly-cannot-import-name-exceptions)

PS2: In case this helps, here is my sys.path output:

```
['',
'C:\\Users\\janfe\\Anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\plotly\\plotly',
'C:\\Users\\janfe\\Anaconda3\\python36.zip',
'C:\\Users\\janfe\\Anaconda3\\DLLs',
'C:\\Users\\janfe\\Anaconda3\\lib',
'C:\\Users\\janfe\\Anaconda3',
'C:\\Users\\janfe\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages',
'C:\\Users\\janfe\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32',
'C:\\Users\\janfe\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
'C:\\Users\\janfe\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin',
'C:\\Users\\janfe\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\IPython\\extensions',
'C:\\Users\\janfe\\.ipython']
```

Comment: `'C:\\Users\\janfe\\Anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\plotly\\plotly'` is strange. `plotly` does something bad, IMHO - they have three modules named "plotly" (`plotly`, `plotly/plotly` and `plotly/plotly/plotly.py`). With that path in `sys.path`, you are importing the internal `plotly/plotly/plotly.py` which masks the real base `plotly` so you get the error. The question is where that path came from... and I have no idea. I don't get it on my standard linux install but I don't use anaconda or windows so don't know what is supposed to happen there. Any chance your `os.getcwd()` is that path?

Comment: Hey, thank you so much! So my ```os.getcwd()``` is completely different, namely the place were I store my project ```'C:\\Users\\janfe\\GD\\DS\\Shared\\FRED\\Python'```

Comment: To get more clear, there are 2 folders created if I install plotly in my ```site-packages``` folder. Both of which can be found here:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1VV9xP_xALYsLVCFODzw2SeJr5OUPPeeC?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1fr3UkOF1lj0NZy-agIINodRNvd3OFpCO?usp=sharing

Comment: I cloned the source from https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py. it has a readme `build_for_conda.md` that says the anaconda build is maintained at https://anaconda.org/chohner/plotly. That page requires a login so I didn't go any further, but maybe there is more information there. Also, check for `.pth` files which may be adding to the path. They are described at https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html. Good luck!

Comment: Solution:
@tdelaney gave the right tip: For some reason ```'C:\\Users\\janfe\\Anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\plotly\\plotly'``` leads Python to try and import plotly from this path, which is impossible. Removing that directory from sys.path solved the problem. No idea how it got inn there...

Comment: How did you remove it? If you found out where it is in the python configuration it would be a useful answer to your own question.

Comment: Oh right sorry. I simply used ```import sys``` and ```sys.path``` to pull up the list of paths and used ```del sys.path[1]``` to get rid of the path.